# Sizing a cell with a webView using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a cell whose only view is a `WKWebView`, pinned to all sides of the `contentView`. The table view I'm displaying it in is set to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the row height. Is there any way to communicate to the system what size to make the cell with a web view in it?

Currently, I implement the following delegate method in order to set all sorts of frames I thought may have an impact on how iOS sizes the cells:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetWidth") {
        (result: (Any?, Error?)) in

        print("\(result)")
        let width = CGFloat((result.0 as! NSNumber).floatValue)
        self.contentView.frame.size.width = width
        self.webView.frame.size.width = width
        self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.width = width

        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight") {
        (result: (Any?, Error?)) in

        print("\(result.0)")
        let height = CGFloat((result.0 as! NSNumber).floatValue)
        self.contentView.frame.size.height = height
        self.webView.frame.size.height = height
        self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height = height

        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.delegate?.didFinishLoading()
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm setting the height and the width to match the HTML string I loaded into the web view. My delegate callback simply calls `reloadData` on the table view. However, this seems to have no effect at all on the size of the cell in the table view, both before and after loading the content, iOS sizes it to 44 points high.

I've set `isScrollingEnabled` to `false` on the scroll view, but that doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Does anyone know how iOS makes its table view calculations? I'd like to be able to fit this in nicely with my current set up if possible and have iOS size the cell properly based off the content loaded to the webview, but it's seeming like this may not be possible.

Edit: I've tried overriding the following two methods, but when I set breakpoints on them, it seems they're never called like I'd expect?

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return self.webView.scrollView.contentSize
}

override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return self.webView.scrollView.contentSize
}
```

Comment: Just as a check, can you make sure youve setup the self sizing cells correctly by using a very simple cell with a label. I suspect it wont work either.

Comment: Make sure to implement "estimated height for cell..." and return automaticdimension

Comment: Also you maybe getting a bogus value from the webviews content size. See what happens when you return a fixed size.

Comment: I can get a simple cell with a label to set up fine, and I do set the `estimatedHeight` and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. I suspect the base issue may be the fact that the webView contains a scrollVIew, which may be messing up the sizing of the cell?

Comment: @BillL I was trying something very similar to you and what I discovered is that by the time WKWebView has finished loading the tableview has already finished deciding how to render the cell, and so the cell got laid out with an empty WKWebView.  Afterwards the html gets displayed (I can see part of its first line), but alas too late.